# Protect API using string key and if statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, security

Is it good practice protecting API:
I have a bot in telegram, from this bot Im calling my API on the same machine, but it is other process on other port. For authorization I send a key of 64 symbols. Pseudo code:

**Bot:**

```
bot.getUserMessage('update_profile', (telegramID, data) => {
  request('http://81.125.67.313/profile/update', 
     { telegramID, data, secretKey: "123topSecret222" });
})
```

**API Server:**

```
api.post('/', (telegramID, data, secretKey) => {
  if (secretKey !== '123topSecret222') return 'error';
  ...do some cool staff;
})`
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you call your API from, but if it's from a browser, you have to know that all JS code in a browser is public, so everybody will see `"123topSecret222"`.

Comment: Also, in your Node server, if you hardcode `if (secretKey !== '123topSecret222')` and you git it, then anybody with further access to your code (developer fellows, contributors, etc.) will see your secret key in clear. Better put it safe in a `.env` file, and read it as `process.env.apiKey` (see the dotenv module)